# PowerShell : How to Get Indentity information from .appx package path?

Tags: powershell, appx, appxmanifest

I'm trying to write a powershell script where

A- Try to install the package from the Path.

B- If the package is already installed, try to uninstall the old version

C- ReTry Step A.

To do the step B, I've tried to get `AppxPackageManifest` with

`$Manifests =  Get-AppxPackageManifest -Package $DeveloperPackagePath.Name`

(where `DeveloperPackagePath` is the full path to the package file.)

Because I need the `Identity` information to remove the application.

But `$Manifests` is empty.

Path is valid, and App package is valid too.

Is there a way to get the Identity information with the path to the package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see in the [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx/get-appxpackagemanifest?view=win10-ps) the cmdlet that gets the manifests works only for **installed packages**, not for their source.

What you want can be done, but you need to work more the get the identity. First you need to use [makeappx.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/appxpkg/make-appx-package--makeappx-exe-#to-extract-files-from-a-package) to extract the package in a temporary location and then you can parse the XML file to get the identiy.

Comment: I've actually managed to do a workaround, I've extracted the .xml file from the .appx and read the identity info. (deleted it at the end of the script)

Anyway, thank you for your answer.